# alignment of a element while y scroll

Tags: html, css, positioning

What i want to is when somebody use y scroll even in that case the header (which contains days and dates should be visible.) Please check [the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0WwE.png)

Something using position:fixed and z-index etc.

(example i have seen :-- when u open stack-overflow and ur JavaScript is disabled, then in that case a red colored message will appear and keep appearing even if u scroll down the page.)

So What i want to do is:--

Initially at page load this row will the be in between the page (as there are lot of other things above and once user scroll down it should be visible to user ie this sticks with the top of the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for an element that is not located at the top of the page, but sticks to the top when you scroll down past it?  This can be done with css and a little JavaScript magic (jQuery used for brevity):

```
/* CSS - you should add width, height, padding as needed */
#your_element { position:relative;}
```

Your element will behave normally if JS is disabled.  Otherwise, the following snippet makes it dynamic:

```
win = $(window);
element = $('#your_element');

if (element.length) {                // <-- Make sure element exists
    win.scroll(function () {         // <-- When scrolling do the following
        if (win.scrollTop() > 100) { // <-- Adjust number.  Explanation to follow
            element.css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0px'});
        } else {
            element.css({'position':'relative', 'top':'auto'});
        }
    });
}
```

Now you just have to adjust the value `100` to equal the distance between the top of the page and the top of your element.  So, if your element is `250px` from the top, you would use `250`.  If you are not sure you can play around with it until you get something that looks smooth.

Comment: It should be noted that regardless of the method, I can't think of any way to accomplish this without using Javascript - users with it turned off will NOT see this effect, but on the other hand, it degrades pretty gracefully - the effect simply doesn't happen, which shouldn't be extremely detrimental to the page's functionality.